# Probability that an integer contains no $1\bmod 4$ prime factor

Tags: nt.number-theory, probabilistic-number-theory

$n$ represents integer variable.

What is the probability that and integer contains at most $r(n)$ prime factors of form $1\bmod 4$ where $r(n)$ is a function of $\omega(n)$ (number of distinct prime factors of $n$)?

What is the probability that and integer contains at most $r_t(n)$ prime factors of form $(2t+1)\bmod 2^k$ prime factor where $t\in\{0,\dots,2^{k-1}-1\}$ where $r_t(n)$ is a function of $\omega(n)$ (number of distinct prime factors of $n$)?

Comment: It is zero, by a simple sieve. For a reference explaining this I can recommend the text by Murty and Cojocaru (*An Introduction to Sieve Methods and Their Applications*).

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov $r$ is a parameter (not fixed).

Comment: Then please revise your question as it is unclear what you are asking. For every $r$, the density is zero. How is $r$ being a parameter different from $r$ being fixed?

Comment: what if $r$ scales with some power of $\omega(n)$?

Comment: OK, you mean $r$ to be a function of $\omega(n)$. This is a fair question, but do you have a particular choice of $r$ that you need for your application?

Comment: I am only thinking about $\omega(n)^{1/\alpha}$. I just want to see **1.** how frequently such numbers occur, **2.** how often numbers with these forms and with even parity of $1\bmod4$ factors with product of these factors dominate that integer occur among integers due to their importance to sum of squares form?

Comment: sloppily written: if these type of factors occur as a large fraction of $\omega(n)$ then we know that number is pretty close to being written as sum of squares.

Comment: What does it mean for a number to be close to being written as a sum of (two) squares? Is 15 closer to being a sum of two squares than 3 is?

Comment: the number of factors which cannot be written as sum of squares is small.

Comment: $5*17*29*31$ is closer than $5*17*23*31$ to being written as sum of squares.

Comment: Why shouldn't the mean and variance of the number of prime factors of $n\leq X$ that are $a$ mod $q$ ($(a,q)=1$) just be $1/\phi(q) \log\log{X} and $O(1/\phi(q) \log\log{X})$ by the same argument as the one for all prime factors (plus Dirichlet's theorem)?

Comment: If you want to be sure, Arul, that I see a comment directed to me, then you have to write @Gerry in it somewhere.

Comment: @GerryMyerson got it.